# ¿Como veo los volúmenes expuestos de un contenedor docker?

Tags: docker

Hola monte hace un tiempo un conetenedor de una forma como esta:

```
docker run \
-d -p  80:80 \
-p 443:443 \
-v "$(pwd)"/crt:/etc/ssl/certs \
-v "$(pwd)"/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d \
-v "$(pwd)"/web:/var/www/html \
--name test01 atareao/nginx:autocertificado
```

Pero no recuerdo que archivos expuse, no recuerdo que rutas use. 
¿Como puedo ver volumenes expuestos y de mas de un contenedor?
¿como puedo ver los

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes inspeccionar el contenedor con:

```
docker inspect test01
```

Te saldrá un extenso JSON. Busca la sección `"Mounts"`

#### Bonus

Si tienes instalado [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (una herramienta para extraer información de JSON desde línea de comandos usando un lenguaje propio para la consulta) puedes utilizarlo en la siguiente forma:

```
docker inspect test01 | jq '.[].Mounts[]| "\(.Source):\(.Destination)"'
```

y te imprimirá algo del estilo:

```
/home/foo/folder/crt:/etc/ssl/certs
/home/foo/folder/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
/home/foo/folder/web:/var/www/html
```